# How do I create a shortcut on Windows to launch Urxvt w/ Cygwin bash but also with certain options beforehand?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, cygwin, urxvt

Confusing title, I know. Here's the problem:

To launch Urxvt in such a way that my extensions work, I'd open up Cygwin and use `export DISPLAY=:0` and then `urxvt`. If I launch urxvt just with `urxvt` then various extensions like clipboard don't work since the original Cygwin window that I launched urxvt from receives the extension inputs (which is why `export DISPLAY=:0` is important.

It was annoying to have to open Cygwin everytime I wanted to run a Urxvt window, so I modified my Cygwin.bat from this:

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin
bash --login -i
```

to this to launch Urxvt as my default terminal emulator:

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin
urxvt -e /bin/bash --login -i
```

And it worked fine for launching Urxvt without having to open any other windows, but the only issue is that my extensions don't work since I obviously didn't put `set DISPLAY=:0` somewhere in the process before launching Urxvt.

So my question is, how can I create a shortcut that launches Urxvt but also prefaces the launch with `set DISPLAY=0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I create a shortcut that launches Urxvt with set DISPLAY=0?

Add the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Note:

- `DISPLAY` should be set to `:0` **not** `0`

---

#### Making Permanent Environment Variables:

> Environment variables are variables that any command, program, or
>   script can access. If a variable is set in a script, only that script
>   can use it. If a user creates a variable in a terminal, the variable
>   can only be used in that terminal until it closes. Then, the variable
>   is gone forever. Users can make permanent environment variables by
>   putting them in the file ~/.bashrc. This file contains functions and
>   variables that the shell sets up when the user opens a terminal.
>   Because the file is in the user's home folder, only that user can
>   access the data that is created from that file. Users may put aliases
>   in here instead of the alias file. The bashrc file loads the alias
>   file into itself. Users typically put their aliases in the alias file,
>   but this is not required.
>
> To create a permanent environment variable, open ~/.bashrc in a
>   preferred text editor. If a user wanted to make a variable that
>   contained the uppercase Greek alphabet, they would set this variable
>   assignment with the other variables being set in this file. To prevent
>   an accidental code mess up in this file, put the new variable at the
>   very end of the file.

Source [Customize BASH](http://www.linux.org/threads/customize-bash.4129/)